# How can I give columns unique names when joining a table to itself?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Say I have a table in a MySQL database, called `people`. `people` has many many columns, one of which is `parent`, which holds the primary key for another row in `people`. I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT people.*, parents.*
FROM
    people
    LEFT JOIN people AS parents ON people.parent = parents.id
```

So as to get a bunch of rows, each one of which holds the data for a person *and* their parent. The problem is, then I get a bunch of duplicate columns, so I can't easily refer to the child's name or the parent's name, for example.

Say there are too many columns in the `people` table to make listing them all out and disambiguating with `AS` feasible. Can something be done to automatically give different names to `parents.name` and `people.name` and so on?

I'm using SQLAlchemy in Python, so any solution that can be achieved with that tool is fine.

Comment: `SELECT parent.id, child.id FROM people parent LEFT JOIN people child ON ....`

Comment: @Rogue I don't see what you mean. This is only going to give me the IDs, no?

Comment: well you can select however you like, the point was to show how to make simple aliases, and then you can refer to them via `parent.column_name`. This is the ideal solution imo, not aliasing the columns themselves.

Comment: @Rogue Doesn't seem to work with SQLAlchemy. When I take one of the rows I get back and run  `row.keys()` I get `['id', 'name', 'parent', 'id', 'name', 'parent']`. No  apparent convenient way to get the child's fields or the parent's fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could join against a select of the columns you need and give them alises:
SELECT people.*, parents.*
FROM people
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, col1 as colA, col2 as colb ... FROM people) AS parents 
ON people.parent = parents.id